# How to run Spark shell with Spark on Mesos?

Tags: submit, apache-spark, jobs, mesos

Is there any way to run an example (SparkPi) from the Spark shell? Or to submit Spark jobs through shell to Mesos cluster? The `spark-submit` currently does not support deployment to Mesos, but I wish to achieve something like that, to have the driver placed to an executor as well.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can connect your spark-shell and spark-submit to Mesos cluster:

```
./bin/spark-shell -h

Usage: ./bin/spark-shell [options]
Options:
  --master MASTER_URL         spark://host:port, mesos://host:port,     yarn, or local.
  --deploy-mode DEPLOY_MODE   Whether to launch the driver program locally ("client") or
                          on one of the worker machines inside the cluster ("cluster")
                          (Default: client).
...
```

2) Is there any way to run an example (SparkPi) from the Spark shell?

In short - Yes. But it will probably only work in Spark 2.0.

Implementation of SparkPi example in Spark 1.6 tries to create new Spark Context (while spark-shell already created one - it will cause problems).

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/SparkPi.scala

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Pi")
val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Implementation in Spark 2.0 tries to reuse existing Spark Context:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.0/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/SparkPi.scala

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("Spark Pi")
  .getOrCreate()
```

So how to start SparkPi from the shell? There you go:

```
./bin/spark-shell --jars ./examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.0.jar 
scala> org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi.main(Array("100"))
Pi is roughly 3.1413147141314712
```